# How can I check if my wrapper function system call - read()  is correct?

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Inline Assembler for wrapper function doesn’t work for some reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10260178/inline-assembler-for-wrapper-function-doesnt-work-for-some-reason)

I'm requested to write wrapper function for `read , write , close , open & fork` .

I've written 4 wrapper functions for `read , write , close , open` .

My questions are :

1. How can I write wrapper function for `fork` , using the 4 wrapper functions that I wrote for `read , write , close & open` ?
2. How can I check if the wrapper that I wrote is correct ? Here is the code for the wrapper function of `read` - called `my_read` :

```
ssize_t my_read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count)   
{    
      ssize_t res;

      __asm__ volatile(
        "int $0x80"        /* make the request to the OS */
        : "=a" (res),       /* return result in eax ("a") */
          "+b" (fd),     /* pass arg1 in ebx ("b") */
          "+c" (buf),     /* pass arg2 in ecx ("c") */
          "+d" (count)      /* pass arg3 in edx ("d") */
        : "a"  (5)          /* passing the system call for read to %eax , with call number 5  */
        : "memory", "cc"); 

      /* The operating system will return a negative value on error;
       * wrappers return -1 on error and set the errno global variable */

      if (-125 <= res && res < 0)
      {
        errno = -res;
        res   = -1;
      }

      return res;
}
```

**Remarks** : I'm not allowed to use directly the `open ,close ,read , write & fork` commands .

I can attach the rest of the code of the other 3 wrappers , if it is needed . The above is the wrapper for `read`.

Regards

Ron

Answer (score 0):

Fork should be system call 2, so

```
    __asm__ volatile ("int $0x80" : "=a" (res) : "0" (2));
```

should work. Remember, fork returns twice, with `res` being the pid of the child(in the parent) and 0(in the child).