# Inline Assembler for wrapper function doesn't work for some reason

Tags: c, assembly, volatile, system-calls

I'm trying to write a wrapper function for read() system call , using 
asm volatile , but it won't work , since the res doesn't change its value  .

Here's the code :

```
ssize_t my_read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count)

{

      ssize_t res;

      __asm__ volatile(
        "int $0x80"        /* make the request to the OS */
        : "=a" (res),       /* return result in eax ("a") */
          "+b" (fd),     /* pass arg1 in ebx ("b") */
          "+c" (buf),     /* pass arg2 in ecx ("c") */
          "+d" (count)      /* pass arg3 in edx ("d") */
        : "a"  (5)          /* passing the system call for read to %eax , with call number 5  */
        : "memory", "cc"); /* announce to the compiler that the memory and condition codes have been modified */

      /* The operating system will return a negative value on error;
       * wrappers return -1 on error and set the errno global variable */

      if (-125 <= res && res < 0)
      {
        errno = -res;
        res   = -1;
      }

      return res;

}
```

and here is `int main ()` :

```
 int main() {
     int fd = 432423;
     char buf[128];
     size_t count = 128;
     my_read(fd, buf, count);

     return 0;
 }
```

Am I doing something wrong ? maybe it's because of the `volatile` ?

I've tried to debug the code , and when Eclipse goes into `my_read(fd, buf, count);`  and 
gets to the line  `__asm__ volatile(` in `my_read` , it fails and goes into `if (-125 <= res && res < 0)` ...

**EDIT :**

```
ssize_t my_read(int fd, void *buf, size_t count)

{

      ssize_t res;

      __asm__ volatile(
        "int $0x80"        /* make the request to the OS */
        : "=a" (res)       /* return result in eax ("a") */

        : "a"  (5) ,      /* passing the system call for read to %eax , with call number 5  */
          "b" (fd),     /* pass arg1 in ebx ("b") */
          "c" (buf),     /* pass arg2 in ecx ("c") */
          "d" (count)      /* pass arg3 in edx ("d") */

        : "memory", "cc"); /* announce to the compiler that the memory and condition codes have been modified */

      /* The operating system will return a negative value on error;
       * wrappers return -1 on error and set the errno global variable */

      if (-125 <= res && res < 0)
      {
        errno = -res;
        res   = -1;
      }

      return res;

}
```

and main :

```
 int main() {
     int fd = 0;
     char buf[128];
     size_t count = 128;
     my_read(fd, buf, count);

     return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> it fails and goes into `if (-125 <= res && res < 0)`

Where did you expect it to go?

I expect the read system call to fail with `-EINVAL`, as you are not pasing in a valid file descriptor to it.

Update:

Where did you get an idea that `SYS_read` is `5`?

On my system, `SYS_read` is `3` in 32-bit mode, and `0` in 64-bit mode:

```
echo "#include <syscall.h>" | gcc -xc - -dD -E | grep ' __NR_read '
#define __NR_read 0

echo "#include <syscall.h>" | gcc -xc - -dD -E -m32 | grep ' __NR_read '
#define __NR_read 3
```

Assuming you are on 32-bit system, you are invoking `SYS_open`, which is failing with `-EFAULT` (-14) because the first parameter to the open system call is supposed to be a filename and `0` (`NULL`) isn't a valid filename.

Comment: @EmployedRussian : One thing is still bothering me : if the file descriptor is int , then what am I doing wrong here ? I passed it int.

Comment: You need a *valid* file descriptor, not just any `int`. Usually one gets a valid file descriptor from an `open` system call. Or use one of the pre-existing ones: `0` (for `stdin`).

Comment: @EmployedRussian : I've tried with "0" using the fixed code in my edited post , but I still go straight into "if (-125 <= res && res < 0)"...

Comment: You haven't correct your `main` (or at least I can't see the correction). Assuming you did correct it, run your program under `strace` as @R.. suggested, and see what it tells you.

Answer (score 2):

Run it under `strace` to see what's happening for sure, but I think your problem is that you put all the inputs in the output register list rather than the input register list...

Comment: How can you see that I put all the inputs in the output register list rather than the input register list ? thanks

Comment: The stuff after the first colon is outputs. The stuff after the second colon is inputs. Right now your only input is the syscall number.

Comment: I've edited my post with you remarks ,is it correct ?  thanks , however something is still wrong and code won't go into asm volatile . Did I miss something else ?

Comment: You're still passing an invalid file descriptor. Unless you call `open`, 0 is the only file descriptor likely to be valid for reading

Comment: I have, I passed "0" (edited in my original post) but it did not help , and went into fail . Maybe the code is incorrect ?